# Markdown package not working despite `--shell-escape` enabled

Tags: markdown, shell-escape

I am trying to use this [markdown package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/markdown). I tried to compile the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}
\begin{document}
    \begin{markdown}
        _Hello,_ [Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com)!
    \end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex -shell-escape`. In the resulting pdf, I just get the markdown code in typewriter font. The interesting part of the log file seems to be

```
\openout3 = `document.markdown.in'.

Package markdown Info: Buffering markdown input into the temporary input file "
document.markdown.in" and scanning for the closing token sequence "\end{markdow
n}" on input line 4.
Package markdown Info: The ending token sequence was found on input line 6.
Package markdown Info: Including markdown document "./document.markdown.in" on 
input line 6.
\g_tmpa_iow=\write6
\openout6 = `document.markdown.lua'.


Package luabridge Info: Writing a helper Lua script to file
(luabridge)             \markdownOptionHelperScriptFileName 


Package luabridge Info: Executing a helper Lua script from file
(luabridge)             \markdownOptionHelperScriptFileName 


(|texlua ./document.markdown.lua)
(./_markdown_document/9d5242e42cdbaaa17c844f6b5db64466.md.tex) [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./docu
ment.aux)
```

which seems okay to me; at least, I see no error messages. The tex file mentioned in the log reads

```
\markdownRendererDocumentBegin
\markdownRendererInputVerbatim{./_markdown_document/9d5242e42cdbaaa17c844f6b5db64466.verbatim}\markdownRendererDocumentEnd
```

and that file in turn is just the original markdown. Calling `\markdownRendererInputVerbatim` seems wrong, given only the macro's name. What's going wrong?

Comment: you are indenting your line, and in markdown that means code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

as for code blocks on this site indent of 4 spaces means verbatim

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}
\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}
  _Hello,_ [Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com)!
\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. That was insanely stupid… thanks.

Comment: @Bubaya No, I don't think it was, it's not easy to shift from a language where indentation is meaningless to one where it matters!

Comment: @Clément although asking a question on a markdown site where indentation has the same effect might have given a clue:-) (but  I agree the question is reasonable, and will hit other people too, handling source indentation of code blocks is tricky in all markup languages)